# Como quitar la barra de titulo de un JInternalFrame - Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Quisiera saber como quitar la barra de titulo de un JInternalFrame.
He estado intentando con este código pero no se borra la barra.

```
   setUI(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomo como [referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218608/hiding-title-bar-of-jinternalframe-java) la solución que me funcionó:

```
((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI)this.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);
```

Comment: excelente amigo gracias!! es lo que necesitaba!

Comment: Por favor, podría ayudarme explicando como se lo usa.